React antd multi-select scrollbar
I have a antd select component as shown below:
<Select
   mode="multiple"
   className='select-input width-220px custom-multiselect'
   value={this.state.selectedColumns}
   onChange={this.handleAdditionalColumnsChange}
   optionLabelProp="label"
   maxTagCount={2}
   maxTagPlaceholder={(omittedValues) => `+${omittedValues.length} more`}
   showArrow={true}

   dropdownRender={(menu) => (
      <div>
         <div className='flex-row justify-space-between padding-4px'>
            <button onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()} type='button' className='clear-selection-button' onClick={() => this.handleClearSelected()}>Clear Selected</button>
            <button onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()} type='button' className='dropdown-button button-bg-color-blue' onClick={() => this.handleSave}>Save</button>
            <button onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()} type='button' className='dropdown-button button-bg-color-white'>Apply</button>
         </div>
         {menu}
      </div>
   )}
>
   {this.props.additionalColumns.map((column) => (
      <Select.Option key={column.columnName} value={column.columnName} label={column.displayname}>
         <Checkbox
            checked={column.isMandatory === 'Y' || this.state.selectedColumns.includes(column.columnName)}
            disabled={column.isMandatory === 'Y'}
            onChange={(e) => {
               this.handleCheckboxChange(column.columnName, e.target.checked);
                    
               this.handleCheckboxChangeForUuid(column.columnUuid, e.target.checked);
            }}
                    
         >
            {column.displayname}
         </Checkbox>
      </Select.Option>
   ))}
</Select>

After I select multiple items, the items are overflowing out of the bounds of select component.

To rectify that I added a scroll option:
.custom-multiselect .ant-select-selector {
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

But it doesn't seem to work.
I want to add a scroll option in the select component to show all the selected items.

What you've tried is right, but just override the class .ant-select-selection--multiple, like this:
.ant-select-selection--multiple {
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

this should work
